# Mesh sticking to edges when using subdivision surface

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Amateur with Blender here, using 2.8, having an issue with the Subdivision surface modifier. I have a very simple shape here and I'm trying to extrude while using the modifier, I have this one part of the mesh that sticks to the edges of the model.

[image: subdivision glitch]

I've tried everything I could think even, I've even deleted all the vertices in that area and rebuilt it from scratch and that darn thing just reappears. If I delete all the edges and then just fill in the new face, it'll just move to the next edge down. I definitely don't have any overlapping points.

[image: Deleted vertices]

Comment: This is inverted normals. Edit mode, select all, shift N will solve that

Answer (score 3):

Normals are inverted either on right or left of the model.

To solve it:

- Edit mode
- Select all <kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

An easy way to detect this is to use X ray:

[image]