# How to fix this Mesh please (two planes with merged vertices)

Tags: mesh

(two planes with merged vertices)

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148479/mesh-sticking-to-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface/148499#148499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normals orientation issue. First, check your normals by enabling the Normals Overlay:

[image: check normals]

- blue normals are pointing outside
- red normals are pointing inside

The shading error comes from Blender not knowing how to get from one orientation to the other any more. Fix the normals by re-calculating them (this will make the orientation consistent across the model) in Edit Mode:

[image: fix normals]

Comment: Thank you this worked! Very helpful.
Thank you for the explanation, makes me understand blender more. :)

Answer (score 1):

Select all of the mesh <kbd>A</kbd> in edit mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.
This will recalculate the normals.

Comment: What does that do and how does it help? And *Select all the mesh* means selecting the vertices or edges or faces or the objects transform?

Comment: @Leander it recalculates normals, select all the mesh in edit mode, doesn't matter if you're in edge select mode or face or vertex, just press "a" in edit mode to select all the mesh then press ctrl+shift+n.

Comment: @Leander also as aliasguru explained check the orientation of the normals, you can use shift+n instead of ctrl+shift+n based on which direction you need.