# subdivision surface acting strange

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

so i'm working on a model and it comes time to clean up the head and when i use sub-surf it works in some places but in others it seems bound to the vertices making it difficult to get a smooth product, there are also no overlapping vertices and when the vertices is deleted it seem to fix the problem until it is recreated either with extrusion or merging.

EX :

[image]

Comment: Maybe something similar to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148479/mesh-sticking-to-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface/148499#148499

Comment: There could be (1) internal faces [hidden] (2) extra extruded vertices [hidden] (3) ripped edges (4) ripped edges caused by not merging the mirror axis vertices of the mirror modifier.