# Weird sharp vertices with subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling

I have a simple skull model, to which I applied the subdivision modifier. For the most part everything works as expected, except I keep getting these weird sharp vertices and I can't seem to figure out how to *flatten* them.

[image]

I'm using Blender 2.8. Is this some kind of feature I can disable/enable for particular vertices? The distance between the *sharp* vertices and the gray outline differ.

[image]

Any suggestions please? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I also tried selecting as both - vertexes and edges and then applied **Edge->Clear Sharp**, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can be this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148479/mesh-sticking-to-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface/148499#148499

Comment: @lemon thank you so much, that was it!! If you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typical of inverted normals.

To fix it, go in edit mode, select all the vertices and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.

[image]