# How to flatten surface?

Tags: faces, topology, subdivision-surface

my problem is the following: I am making Blender Guru's Chair Tutorial Series and I want to have a flat edge, but it makes this round shape and messes up my surface.

Thanks in advance,
Tobi

[image: Problem Wireframe]
[image: Problem Solid View]

Comment: Inverted normals, most likely, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151374/weird-sharp-vertices-with-subdivision-modifier/151378#151378

Comment: select the vertex that is down and bring it up in the z axis. But most questions about tutorials are solved if you watch the video again and notice what you did differently.

Comment: @Squizy Can u share your .blend file if none of those help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an inverted normal to me. Go into edit mode, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.

Comment: I did recalculate the normals and it didn't change anything.

I think it has sthg to do with this random face popping up. There is a face where the line is going down in the middle. You cant see it on the screenshot.

Comment: I would recommend going into wireframe mode and removing any internal geometry that isn't supposed to be there. you can access wireframe mode by hitting z in the viewport and clicking wireframe.

Comment: That worked out fine, sorry forgot to come back and give you feedback! Thanks Michael!

Answer (score 1):

there are a million ways in which your mesh could be messed up , but in majority of case this is either a flipped normal or you have a bad modeling workflow , if recalculating nor,als dont work , you can try deleting the vertex itself and then filling the 4 vertices